# Update JIRA field with a value from a csv file using Ruby and REST

Tags: salesforce, jira

Need to do this in order to update historic data after a recent JIRA upgrade. Did anyone try this?

Any help would be appreciated,

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Simply run over all CSV lines:

```
CSV.foreach('JiraIssues.csv',
            :quote_char=>'"',
#           :force_quotes => true,
            :col_sep =>";",
            :headers => true,
            :header_converters => :symbol ) do |row|

    processField(row[:com_jiraid] , row[:value])
end
```

The processField method would include what you asked for in [Updating Jira custom field using Jira-Ruby gem (REST API) does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655015/updating-jira-custom-field-using-jira-ruby-gem-rest-api-does-not-work)