# Updating Jira custom field using Jira-Ruby gem (REST API) does not work

Tags: jira

I have the following code (from jira-ruby gem api doc). It successfully updates the "Comments" but not the customfield value in Jira. I made sure the name of the custom field is correct in the json dump. Suggest any alternatives?

any help is much appreciated,

```
output = File.new("jira_dump2.json","w+")

issue = client.Issue.find("DEV-XXXXX")
output.puts issue.to_json

#this throws no errors and does not work
issue.save({"fields"=>{"customfield_11530"=>"a0x40000000PHet"}})

#this following code works
comment = issue.comments.build
comment.save!(:body => "This is a comment added from REST API newer" )
```

Answer (score 1):

A good start is to use curl for a similar call:

```
curl -D- -u user:password -X PUT --data @request.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://jira-server:port/rest/api/2/issue/DEV-XXXXX
```

(replace user, password, jira-server and port)

The file request.txt should contain the json request:

```
{"fields":{"customfield_11530":"a0x40000000PHet"}}
```

In my case that worked however the jira-ruby gem made a different request: it used a path like /rest/api/2/issue/22241 that resulted in a 400 Bad Request error with the body message

```
"Field 'customfield_11530' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."
```

To fix the gem I changed these lines in base.rb in the gem

```
417       if @attrs['self']
418         @attrs['self'].sub(@client.options[:site],'')
419       elsif key_value
420         self.class.singular_path(client, key_value.to_s, prefix)
```

to this:

```
417       if key_value
418         self.class.singular_path(client, key_value.to_s, prefix)
419       elsif @attrs['self']
420         @attrs['self'].sub(@client.options[:site],'')
```

(on my machine in "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jira-ruby-0.1.2/lib/jira")

That did the trick. Hopefully it works for you as well.
Here you can check the state of the issue in the maintainer's JIRA system: http://jira.sumoheavylabs.com/browse/JR-3 .

If you want to get more error info in your code, do it like this:

```
begin
    issue.save!( updateHash )
rescue JIRA::HTTPError => e
    puts e.response.code
    puts e.response.message
    puts e.response.body  
end
```